# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close Audio player

Tags: flutter, audio, dispose

for my app i use package audioplayers(https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers), and my problem it when i started audio and go back from stateful widget i have error like this:  Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close and when i go back my audio is missing but i can't stoped audio. And i dont know what to do, can someone help me.

```
    enum PlayerState { stopped, playing, paused }
    enum PlayingRouteState { speakers, earpiece }

    class PlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      final String url;
      final PlayerMode mode;

      PlayerWidget({this.url, this.mode = PlayerMode.MEDIA_PLAYER});

      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _PlayerWidgetState(url, mode);
      }
    }

    class _PlayerWidgetState extends State<PlayerWidget> {
      //audio player
      String url;
      PlayerMode mode;
      AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;
      AudioPlayerState _audioPlayerState;
      Duration _duration;
      Duration _position;

      PlayerState _playerState = PlayerState.stopped;
      PlayingRouteState _playingRouteState = PlayingRouteState.speakers;
      StreamSubscription _durationSubscription;
      StreamSubscription _positionSubscription;
      StreamSubscription _playerCompleteSubscription;
      StreamSubscription _playerErrorSubscription;
      StreamSubscription _playerStateSubscription;

      get _isPlaying => _playerState == PlayerState.playing;
      get _isPaused => _playerState == PlayerState.paused;
      get _durationText => _duration?.toString()?.split('.')?.first ?? '';
      get _positionText => _position?.toString()?.split('.')?.first ?? '';

      _PlayerWidgetState(this.url this.mode);

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _initAudioPlayer();
       }

      @override
      void dispose() async {
        _audioPlayer.dispose();
        _durationSubscription?.cancel();
        _positionSubscription?.cancel();
        _playerCompleteSubscription?.cancel();
        _playerErrorSubscription?.cancel();
        _playerStateSubscription?.cancel();
        super.dispose();
      }
  void _initAudioPlayer() {
    _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(mode: mode);
    _durationSubscription = _audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((duration) {
      setState(() => _duration = duration);

      if (Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
        _audioPlayer.startHeadlessService();
        _audioPlayer.setNotification(
            title: name,
            artist: author,
            imageUrl: 'url',
            forwardSkipInterval: const Duration(seconds: 30), // default is 30s
            backwardSkipInterval: const Duration(seconds: 30), // default is 30s
            duration: duration,
            elapsedTime: Duration(seconds: 0));
      }
    });

    _positionSubscription =
        _audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((p) => setState(() {
          _position = p;
        }));

    _playerCompleteSubscription =
        _audioPlayer.onPlayerCompletion.listen((event) {
          _onComplete();
          setState(() {
            _position = _duration;
          });
        });

    _playerErrorSubscription = _audioPlayer.onPlayerError.listen((msg) {
      print('audioPlayer error : $msg');
      setState(() {
        _playerState = PlayerState.stopped;
        _duration = Duration(seconds: 0);
        _position = Duration(seconds: 0);
      });
    });

    _audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        _audioPlayerState = state;
      });
    });

    _audioPlayer.onNotificationPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() => _audioPlayerState = state);
    });

    _playingRouteState = PlayingRouteState.speakers;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you "go back from a stateful widget" it will dispose;

it will call

```
@override
void dispose()
```

where you call `_audioPlayer.dispose();` and my guess is after that you still try to work with _audioPlayer but its already closed

There is two ways to solve that problem

1. create new instance _audioPlayer and work with it
2. save _audioPlayer in some widget like App so you will always keep it 'alive' while a user is in the app

Ps. again a problem is that you still trying to work with _audioPlayer after it was disposed

Comment: sorry, but can you help me with my code, i am new in flutter and in this package have big problems with this. I try your ways and in default i see this error : Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4142 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.

Comment: If you are facing many problems with that package I recommend you to open issue on https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/issues Im sure if you will provide reproducing steps some guys will help you